# Which type safety would have lost, had Generics supported the sub-typing?

Tags: java, generics

Consider the snippet:

```
Number[] numbers = {1, 2.3, 4.5f, 6000000000000000000L};
```

It's perfectly okay to do the above, `Number` is an abstract class.

Going ahead,

```
List<Long> listLong = new ArrayList<Long>();
listLong.add(Long.valueOf(10));

List<Number> listNumbers = listLong; // compiler error    - LINE 3

listNumbers.add(Double.valueOf(1.23));
```

Had Line 3 was designed to be compiled successfully,
we would end up with a `List` of `Number`s, i.e,

```
for(Number num: listNumbers ){
    System.out.println(num);
}

// 10
// 1.23
```

which are all numbers.

I came across this in a book,

> Generics doesn’t support sub-typing because it will cause issues in
>   achieving type safety. That’s why `List<T>` is not considered as a
>   subtype of `List<S>` where `S` is the super-type of `T`

Which type safety would have lost in this ***specific*** case as discussed above, were the Line 3 was to be compile successfully?

Comment: Check out this article about why Java [generics are not covariant](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp01255/).

Comment: `List<? extends Number>` would work. It prevents `add`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
List<Long> listLong = new ArrayList<Long>();
List<Number> listNumbers = listLong;
```

So, `listNumbers` and `listLong` would be two references to the same list, if that was possible, right?

```
listNumbers.add(Double.valueOf(1.23));
```

So, you would be able to add a Double to that list. `listLong`, of type `List<Long>`, would thus contain a Double. The type-safety would thus be broken.

Comment: How can I be so stupid this morning?

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari you're not, it's actually a good question :)

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari In C# they created `in` and `out` (Generic Modifier) for this reason. Look it up if you want to know a strategy that avoids the problem pointed out in this answer.

Comment: It is certainly a good question, and one point of confusion might be because arrays are *not* invariant. This is a bug: they *should* be invariant, because the exact same issue occurs (`long[] longs = { 1, 2 }; Number[] nums = longs; nums[0] = 0.5; }`). However, when Java didn't have generics, arrays were the only way to pass a typed collection, so they wanted *something* to be covariant. Such is life.

Comment: @WorldSEnder For reference, Java has those, too: they're called `? extends T` and `? super T` respectively. Search "generic wildcards constrained" or something. (If `in` and `out` do what I assume they do?)

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari thats a "problem" that relates to mutability. If a List was ummutable, adding a supertype to the List would not modify the List and instead return a List with the parametrized supertype.

Comment: It is beyond me why Oracle chose to no longer host the superb [generics-tutorial.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20050715000000*/http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf).  It answers all questions.

Comment: @WChargin C# works differently, but the general idea is the same. For example, there is no way to write `IList<? extends Number>`, because `IList<T>` doesn't (and can't) have `out`. You can use `IReadOnlyList<out T>` for the same purpose, but the object has to actually implement that interface (in addition to `IList<T>`). Using that, you can write `IReadOnlyList<Number> listNumbers = listLong;`.

Comment: @svick: I must be missing something, because I thought there is a way, namely `IList<T> where T : Number`  Of course, since it is invariant, it can't be used as a `IList<Number>`

Comment: @svick Basically the difference is where you declare contra- respectively covariance. C# has declaration-site variance, while Java has use-site variance. Use-set declarations are more powerful (you avoid lots of code duplication), but at the same time more confusing for your average user. As much as it pains me, declaration-site variance is probably the better approach for mainstream languages.

Comment: @BenVoigt That restricts what `T`s can be used with `IList<T>`. I don't see how is that in any way similar to what you can do in Java: `List<? extends Number> listNumbers = listLong;`.

Comment: @svick: Ahh, it's true that C# doesn't allow it in a variable declaration (only in a class or method signature).  Weird that Java does.

Answer (score 8):

If that was the case, then we could add other different subtypes of `Number` into `listNumbers`, which must be forbidden.

Imagine you're now inserting objects of type `Double` and `Long`, and later you try to use [`Long#reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#reverse-long-). Your code *will* compile but of course will fail at *runtime* (bad) the first `Double` it'll come through.

Answer (score 5):

Let's use an example with a non-abstract base class:

```
public class Human {
    public string getName() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Student extends Human {
    public void learn(Subject subject) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Teacher extends Human {
    public void teach(Subject subject) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

At any place where a `Human` is expected, a `Student` or `Teacher` will do just as well, as they fully implement the `Human` interface. (In this case, that `getName()` can be called on them.) Java inheritance guarantees that this is the case technically. Making it work semantically is the class author's job, so that his code fulfils the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

So doesn't this mean that we can also substitute `Collection<Teacher>` where a `Collection<Human>` is expected? Not always. Consider the following method:

```
public class Human {
    // ...

    public void join(Set<Human> party) {
        party.add(this);
    }
}
```

Now, if Java allowed a `Set<Student>` to be passed as party, any attempts of non-`Student` `Human`s to join that party would have to fail at runtime.

As a general rule, a **container of a subtype** is unsuitable if the receiver (callee in case of a function argument, caller in case of a function return value) wants to put something into it, but acceptable if the receiver only want to take stuff out and use it. A **container of a supertype** is unsuitable if the receiver wants to take stuff out and use it, but acceptable if the receiver only ever puts stuff into it. As a result, if the receiver both takes stuff out of the collection and puts stuff into the collection, they usually must require a collection of a fixed type.

Our `join` method only puts `Human`s into the `party`, so we could also allow a `Set<Object>` or a non-generic `Set` or equivalently a `Set<?>`. Java allows us to do that with [lower-bounded wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html):

```
public class Human {
    // ...

    public void join(Set<? super Human> party) {
        party.add(this);
    }
}
```

For opening up the possibilities towards subclasses, there's [upper-bounded wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html):

```
public class Teacher extends Human {
    public void teach(Subject subject, Set<? extends Student> schoolClass) {
        for (Student student : class) {
            student.learn(subject);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if we ever subclass `Student`, the passed `schoolClass` can be a `Set` of that subtype, too.

Answer (score 3):

The concept you are referring to is [*variance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

In other words, if `S` is a supertype of `T`, is `List<S>` a subtype, supertype, equal type, or unreleted to `List<T>`?

The answer for `List` -- and all other Java generics* -- is "unrelated", i.e. invariant.

```
class SuperType {}

class Type extends SuperType {}

class SubType extends Type {}

List<Type> list = ...

List<SuperType> superList = list;
superList.add(new SuperType());
// no, we shouldn't be able to add a SuperType to list

List<SubType> subList = list;
SubType item = subList.get(0);
// no, there's not necessarily only SubType items in list
```

*Java *does* have the notion of "use-site" variance, with [wildcards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_(Java)) (`?`). This will limit what methods are possible to call.

```
List<Type> list = ...

List<? super SubType> wildcardList = list;
wildcardList.add(new SubType());
// but...everything we get() is an Object
```

or

```
List<Type> list = ...

List<? extends SuperType> wildcardList = list;
SuperType item = wildcard.get(0);
// but...it's impossible to add()
```

---

FYI, some languages have the notion of definition-site variance, e.g. Scala. So `List[Int]` is indeed a subtype of `List[Number]`. That's possible with immutable collections (again, a limited set of methods), but obviously not for mutable ones.